# Getting KeyError of missing `code` argument

Tags: keyerror, authlib

I use authlib with MSAD and I am getting KeyError on line:
https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/integrations/flask_client/integration.py#L43

My question is if there has to be always `code` argument within request or IMHO this is bug and it should be checked by `get()` method same as state.

I use it with flask and after proper registration of MSAD client I try method `authorize_access_token()` and from here I get to the poit of code I mentioned above and get error.

Thanks for any advice.

Vit

Answer (score 0):

Are you using debug mode of Flask? In production, this code will raise 400 Bad request error.